# react-hook-form FormContext default values problem

Tags: react-hook-form

Trying to use **react-hook-form**  FormContext.

I'm supplying deafultValues object in useForm hook. But couldn't manage to populate my component, simple textfield, with the default value in by Bottom.tsx component.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-framework-z2ozd?file=/src/App.tsx:426-433)

Comment: if defaultValues is coming async, you can use reset at useEffect

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you got this working, but I was able to get it working by spreading the methods and using `Controller` for both `TextFields`. Also, you were importing `control` from RHF but it's actually returned from `useFormContext()`

```js
import React from "react";
import Bottom from "./Bottom";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useForm, FormContext } from "react-hook-form";

const App = () => {
  const defaultValues = {
    car: "AUDI",
    city: "Tokyo"
  };
  const { ...methods } = useForm({ defaultValues });

  return (
    <FormContext {...methods}>
      <Grid container direction="column">
        <Grid item>
          <Bottom />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </FormContext>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useFormContext, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

interface BottomProps {}

const Bottom: React.FunctionComponent<BottomProps> = (props: BottomProps) => {
  const { register, control } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <>
      <Controller
        name="city"
        control={control}
        as={
          <TextField
            ref={register}
            style={{ margin: 20 }}
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            label="City"
          />
        }
      />
      <Controller
        name="car"
        control={control}
        as={
          <TextField
            ref={register}
            style={{ margin: 20 }}
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            label="Car"
          />
        }
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Bottom;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-goldwasser-so349?file=/src/App.tsx